# PHP question. I get email, but it doesn't have user input from website

Tags: php, input

The PHP code sends me an email from the server, but the user input is empty or "blank". I only receive: "From: \ Email: \ Subject: \ Message: " and that's it.

How do I fix my PHP and/or HTML code to receive user input from the form? Here is my existing HTML and PHP code that doesn't send me any "user input" from the form.

[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLZR7.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBm7h.png)

Thanks to anyone who can help!!

Comment: welcome to the platform. You might need to look at your form enctype attribute. We could have looked at it but you didn't post it here. And also you might wanna go through this resource (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to better ask a question on this platform

Answer (score -1):

Consider this is your form

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name" required>

<input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="enter name">
```

**Make sure that `<form action=""` is linking to correct page and `method="post"` should be there.
If form is there on current page i.e. in my case its yourpage.php then leave form action blank. Also i recommend adding required in end of input field e.g.**

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter your name" required>
```

as it forces user to write some value there so you dont get a empty value

Next will be your php file, just add a code in first line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

above code verifies that user clicks on submit button so overall code will look like

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phoneT'];
    $call = $_POST['call'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $type = $_POST[itypel];
    $message = $_POSTUmessagefl;
    $formcontent = "  From:$name \n  Phone: $phone \n  CallBack: $call \n Website: $website \n  Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n  Message:    $message";
    $recipient = "YOUREMAIL@HERE.COM";
    $subject - "Contact  Form";
    $mailheader = "From:                 $email                     \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!" . "           -" . "<a  href=iform.htmll
    style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'>  Return
    Home</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this still doesn't work!